# Almost all non-negative real numbers have only finitely many multiple lies in a measurable set with finite measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, ergodic-theory

Let $A$ be Lebesgue measurable subset of $[0,\infty)$ such that Lebesgue measure of $A$ is positive i.e. $0<\lambda(A)<\infty$. Let $S$ be the set defined as follows: 
$$S:=\{t\in [0,\infty):nt\in A\text{ for infinitely many }n\in\Bbb N\}$$

What can we conclude about the measure of $S$?

I can guess that $\lambda (S)=0$ for when $A$ is an open set but can't prove it.
More particular case, when $A$ is open with finitely many components then I can conclude that $\lambda(S)=0$

Answer (score 0):

Define for $N\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$S_N=\{t\in[0,N): nt\in A\text{ for infinitely many 
} n\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$
Then $nS_N\backslash S_N\subset A$ for infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\lambda(nS_N\backslash S_N)\geq\lambda(S_N)$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Continuing in this way You can construct a sequence of disjoint subsets of $A$ of measure at least $\lambda(S_N)$ and thus since $\lambda(A)<\infty$ You can conclude $\lambda (S_N)=0$. It follows
$$\lambda(S)=\lambda(\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}S_N)=0.$$

Comment: Can you explain why does the fact $nS_N\backslash S_N\subset A$ hold for infinitely many $n\in \Bbb N$?

Comment: Good point! Honestly: No, I can't! If $S_N$ is countable $\lambda(S_N)=0$ and You are done, but when $S_N$ is uncountable: For every $t\in S_N$ one has an infinite set $N_t\subset\mathbb{N}$ so that $N_t t\subset A$, but the intersection of this uncountable family of infinite subsets need not be infinite ( see https://mathoverflow.net/q/89306). I will try to fix this but I'm not too optimistic.

Comment: I thought it might be possible to sort out a certain set of measure zero ( e.g. a countable set) to get another set of the same measure so that the claim holds but in view of the result proved in the quoted question this seems misleading and $|\bigcap_{t\in U}N_t|=\aleph_0$ for a subset $U\subset S_N$ of measure $\lambda(U)=\lambda (S_N)$ can't be achieved in general.hmmm...